# Angular Subscription is not call on Next

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to implement an auto-login system where I save the login data to `local storage` so that on refresh I fetch the data from local storage.

When I fetch the data from `local storage` I use `Subject` to `emit` that data so that in the header component I subscribe for the data and maintain the application state on refresh.

Now on refresh, my `autologin function` is getting called but Subscription is not calling in the header component

> AuthService Code

```
    autoLogin(){
    const userdata: {
        email:string;
        id: string;
        _token:string;
        _tokenExpairDate:Date;
    }=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

    if(!userdata){
      return;
    }

    console.log("Auto Login Call");
    
    const loadedData=new User
    (
      userdata.email,
      userdata.id,
      userdata._token,
      new Date
      (
        userdata._tokenExpairDate
      )
    );

    if(loadedData.token){
      console.log(loadedData);
      console.log("data Emmit");
      this.user.next(loadedData);
    }
    else{
      console.log("data Not Emmit");
    }
 }
```

> header component code

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.userSub=this.auth.user.subscribe(user=>{
      console.log("Subscription Call");
      this.isLogin=!user? false:true;
    })
  }
```

Comment: could you also provide code where you "register" your AuthService in modules

Comment: @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {

Comment: do you also put it in `providers` section anywhere?

Comment: Now no but I try that also in app.modules

Comment: is `console.log("Subscription Call");` being executed?

Comment: No its only calling on initial load not on refresh

Comment: Is `auth.user` a Subject, of a BehaviorSubject ? If it is a Subject, it may mean that the `next` is triggered before the subscribe, so the subscribe don't see it

Comment: its subject user =new Subject<User>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am not sure how you are actually setting the observable, but this might help you.

```
// In user.modal.ts export a interface for the user
// You need to define this so that you dont need to repeat your code

export interface User {
    email:string;
    id: string;
    _token:string;
    _tokenExpairDate:Date;
}
************************************
// In your service file, do this: 

import { User } from './user.modal.ts';

let initialUserDetails: User = {};

private userDetailsSource: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(this.initialUserDetails);

public userDetailsObservable: Observable<User> = this.userDetailsSource.asObservable();

setUserDetails(userDetails: User) {
    this.userDetailsSource.next(userDetails);
}

getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
    return this.userDetailsObservable;
}

********************************
// In your component.ts file, whenever you want to set the details: 

if (loadedData.token) {
    console.log(loadedData);
    console.log("data Emmit");
    this.user.next(loadedData); // Dont do this:

    this.yourServiceName.setUserDetails(loadedData); // Do this;
}


// Whenever you want to get the details of the Observable, you can do this: 

this.yourServiceName.getUserDetails().subscribe(subscribedData => {
    console.log('Latest Observable Data =>', subscribedData);
})
```

Comment: Note that using a BehaviorSubject, when you'll subscribe to it, you may receive the init value (here `{}`), and then receive a second event with the real data. So you should add a check in the subscribe. That's the reason why we often use `null` as init value, so it is easy to ignore.